# Error while set the System assigned manage identity for web app

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to set the system assigned managed identity On using Powershell but error displayed.

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -AssignIdentity $true -Name "devt002" -ResourceGroupName "devt002RG"
```

Error :

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AssignIdentity'.
At line:1 char:19
+ Set-AzureRmWebApp -AssignIdentity $true -Name "devt002" -ResourceGrou ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureRmWebApp], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.SetAzureWebAppCmdlet
```

Note : It is working fine when i run it in Cloud shell window.

Comment: Your Azure PowerShell version might be different?

Comment: Not working even in latest powershell 6.1 version.

Comment: I have 6.11 version of AzureRM and I have the AssignIdentity switch on the cmdlet.

Comment: There is some other issue. Downloaded the latest version of powershell -> Install the AzureRm module by running command 'Install-Module -Name AzureRM'. Now when i run any command it says not recognised. e.g : Login-AzureRmAccount : The term 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of the Azure PowerShell cmdlet (you could also directly migrate to the new az cmdlet): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-1.5.0

The CloudShell always uses the latest version, to if it works there, your local version is most likely outdated.